# Listas encadeadas - adicionar no final da lista

Tags: c

to tendo problema na hora de executar esse código, cujo objetivo é adicionar um elemento no final da lista, o programa fica aguardando algo que não sei o que é, então o programa da erro. Alguma luz?

To começando agora listas, então a possibilidade de ser um erro besta é grande hehe.

```
typedef struct evento_t {
double tempo;
char descricao[50];
int id_origem, id_destino;
struct evento_t *prox;
} evento_t;


bool eventos_adicionar_fim (evento_t **lista, double tempo, char descricao[], int   id_origem, int id_destino) {

evento_t *novoelemento = (evento_t*)malloc(sizeof(evento_t));
evento_t *auxiliar = *lista, *anterior = NULL;

if (novoelemento!=NULL) {
    novoelemento->tempo = tempo;
    strcpy (novoelemento->descricao, descricao);
    novoelemento->id_origem = id_origem;
    novoelemento->id_destino = id_destino;
    novoelemento->prox = NULL;

    while (auxiliar!=NULL) {
        anterior = auxiliar;
        auxiliar = auxiliar->prox;
    }

    anterior->prox = novoelemento;

    return true;
}

else {
    exit(1);
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Note que você não previu o caso de a lista ter zero elementos (o while não executará e `anterior` será NULL). Nessa situação faça `*lista = novoelemento;`. Qual é exatamente o erro que você está observando? Crash?

Comment: Cade a definição da função main? Seu código parece estar incompleto. poste aqui pra gente dar uma olhada: http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Poste na própria pergunta, não tem porque por em um local externo.

Comment: Como estou executando pelo cmd, o cmd para de responder.

Já verifiquei o erro do NULL e ainda dá no mesmo. Acho que o main ta correto, porque tenho uma função pra adicionar no inicio e ela ta funcionando normal.

Comment: modifiquei o código

Comment: Execute em um debugger. Se seu compilador for o gcc, compile com `-g` e execute com `gdb prog.exe`. dê o comando `run` e `backtrace` para exibir o local do erro. (Dali você pode também explorar o valor das variáveis)

Comment: Ah, agora foi. Era exatamente o problema do NULL, tinha fechado o bloco do if no lugar errado ^^

Comment: Kay, se você encontrou a solução sozinho, adicione uma resposta a sua própria pergunta, assim completamos o ciclo :)

Comment: Não encontrei sozinho, tinha errado o negócio do NULL que você havia dito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está em tentar inserir algo no fim de uma lista vazia. Nesse caso tanto o `auxiliar` quanto o `anterior` sejam `NULL`. O crash acontecerá ao fazer `anterior->prox = novoelemento;`. Em vez disso adicione uma checagem:

```
if (*lista == NULL) {
    *lista = novoelemento;
} else {
    // código anterior
}
```